# What is NoTrack?

Tags: software-recommendation, privacy

I accidently came across this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcZQPnue1js) regarding a software called [NoTrack](https://github.com/quidsup/notrack). If I am correct its some kind of ad blocking software. Most of the ad blocking softwares which I tried comes as a browser plugin(Adblock plus) this software we have to install it in our system. Is this software for web servers or it can be used in local systems? Because its not from the official repo, is it safe to install it in ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extract from the [`README.md`](https://github.com/quidsup/notrack/blob/master/README.md) file on GitHub:

> NoTrack is a network-wide DNS server which blocks Tracking websites from creating cookies or sending tracking pixels. It does this by resolving the IP address of known tracking sites to a web server running on the NoTrack device inside your network.
>
> [...]
>
> Point the DNS IP of all your systems to your NoTrack device. Or setup DHCP on your NoTrack device using the instructional YouTube video provided.

This looks to me like the application you're talking about sets up a DNS server which you can use in your local home network. It filters out DNS requests to tracking URLs and stops them from loading.

This software is not checked by Canonical or the Ubuntu community for safety or non-maliciousness though, you have to trust the author on your own risk.